# Tikz draw banded diagonal matrix with annotations

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

**Diagram.** I'm still learning TikZ to produce mathematical diagrams.

How can use tikz to generate make the generate such an image in the diagram ?
[image]

Some notes on certain aspects which might not be apparent in my handmade drawing:

- The rectangular box is in fact a perfect square.
- The diagonal band is perfectly symmetric about the diagonal broken line.
- The diagonal band is filled with the color green (or whatever you like).
- The is supposed to be symmetrical about the diagonal (broken line).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last point is unclear (The ??? is supposed...), but the rest seems to be followed:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[very thick] (2,2)--node[above]{$\mathcal{X}$}(-2,2)--node[left]{$\mathcal{X}$}(-2,-2)--(2,-2)--cycle;

\draw[dashed](-2,2)--(2,-2);
\draw[<->] (-0.5,-0.5)--node[above]{$\varepsilon$}(0.5,0.5);

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great. Thanks. What about the annotations $\mathcal X$ on the sides ?

Comment: @dohmatob Oh! The crosses are nor incidental but are X's! Just a minute...

Comment: @dohmatob Please see the corrected code. Should I also change the picture here?

Comment: Thanks. No, that should be fine. I also managed to include it by doing
`
    \node at (-2.3, 0) {\large $\mathcal X$};
    \node at (0, 2.3) {\large $\mathcal X$};        
`